# How to Create a Table with Sub-groups in LaTeX

Tags: tables

How can a table like the one below be created using LaTeX?

[image: Image of a table with a main header row and sub-grouped entries]

I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432450/314147, which achieves a similar concept, but is not exactly what I am looking for.

There are no constraints regarding the use of specific packages.

Comment: IMHO you are looking for `\multicolumn` (to combine the columns for the texts like `Data Transfer` → most LaTeX introductions) and maybe also for package [`hhline`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hhline) or package [`array`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) (for the vertical double lines). But if you would [show us, what you've already tried](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), we would not need to guess, where you failed.

Comment: BTW: Tables like these are ugly. You should avoid vertical lines and lots of horizontal lines or boxes. Better use packages like [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and maybe [`colortbl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) (or even [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), but you need to read more to use this package) to create good looking tables.